# Is a reducible variety projective if each of its irreducible component is?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X=X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_n$ is an irreducible decomposition of variety(scheme). Suppose each $X_i$ is projective, then is $X$ projective? Does this hold for proper case? The local ring at the intersection became unclear to me, I am not sure if the valuation criteria can still be verified at the intersection points? (I am reading the definition of a stable curve, which says a complete curve, or projective curve has some properties, I am not clear projectiveness means to treat each component or the whole can be embedded in some projective space?)

Comment: I do not understand what you want to verify in the local ring of intersection points. However, for stable curves $C$, any power $\omega_C^{\otimes m}$ of the dualizing line bundle is very ample (for $m\geq 3$), so you do not need an embedding for each component.

Comment: Is there a reference for the property or it is very easy? I am not familiar with the dualizing sheaf on a curve in this case..But your answer seems nice!

Comment: A proof is in Deligne-Mumford *The irreducibility of the space of curves of given genus*, Theorem 1.2. I think that paper contains nothing "very easy". But if you forget about "$m\geq 3$" and just want to show ampleness of $\omega_C$, then I think it is a bit easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each $X_i$ is proper, then $X$ is.  (Just check the definition directly; you don't need to use the valuative criterion.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we can have the following counter-example: Take two copies of $\mathbb{P}^3$, pick $L,C$ be disjoint line and conic in the first copy, pick $L',L''$ be disjoint lines in the second copy, then glue $L,L'$, glue $C,L''$. The glued union is projective, because the existence of ample line bundle would imply $1=2$ by intersection theory.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a proof that $X$ must be projective if it's a curve over a field. If each component is projective, then they're also proper, so $X$ is proper (Matt's answer). Then by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629341/proper-curves-over-some-field-are-projective), $X$ must be projective.

Comment: Proper does not imply projective in general.

Comment: Yes you're right, I was assuming that $X$ is a curve (because that is the case I care about) but forgot to mention this. I've edited my answer.