# Proper curves over some field are projective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-schemes

I'm looking for a reference of the statement

> Let $X$ be a proper curve (scheme of dimension one) over the field $k$. Then $X$ is projective.

There is a some kind of guided exercise in Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* (Ex. 7.5.4).

Does someone know a reference? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Assuming the curve is nonsingular, this is Proposition II.6.7 in Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: The only assumption should be being proper over the field $k$.

Comment: Pass to the normalisation, which is projective, and pull back the polarisation. The pull back is still ample over the starting curve, which is then projective.

Comment: @Cla Thank you, but I'm still looking for a reference, which I could cite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reference in the [Stacks-Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/):

We have the statement with the tag [0A26](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A26), which says:

> Let $X$ be a proper scheme over a field $k$. If $\dim(X) \leq 1$, then $X$ is H-projective over $k$.

Now use tag [0B45](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B45), which says that being H-projective and projective is equivalent if the base scheme has an ample invertible sheaf (true for the base $\operatorname{Spec(k)}$).

Answer (score 1):

See Proposition 7.4.9 in EGAII.