# Questions about 1-dimensional scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose $X$ is a regular, Noetherian, separated, connected, one-dimensional scheme over a field $F$.

Questions: (1) Does there always exist a point $P\in A$ such that $X-P$ is an open affine subscheme in $X$ ?

(2)Assume $F$ is algebraic closed. Let $\eta$ be the unique generic point of $X$, and $K=k_{\eta}$ is the function field of $X$. Is the following statement right?

Statement: X is proper if and only if  $\sum_{x\in X}ord_x(f)=0$ for all $f\in K$.

Remark: By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629341/proper-curves-over-some-field-are-projective), we know for a curve, proper  is equivalent to projective.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For (1), the basic idea is that by Riemann-Roch a sufficiently high multiple of $P$ is a very ample divisor, so in the associated projective embedding $X - P$ is a closed subscheme of an affine space (obtained by deleting the hyperplane that $P$ maps to), hence an affine variety.

Comment: You have to be careful to assume that $X$ is also of finite type, I am not sure if part (2) is true without that assumption.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks, I find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594240/must-a-proper-curve-minus-a-point-be-affine).

Comment: @user45878 In [this paper](http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr/TEXTES/Exp1150-Morrow.pdf) by Matthew Morrow, the author doesn't assume $X$ is of finite type when he define a curve in definition 2.6 on page 11. And by his definition, a curve is complete when the degree formula holds. So I wonder if completeness is equivalent to proper...